# PHP How to Make Sub Array from array with unique random result?

Tags: php, arrays, random

My script looks like this:

```
<?php 
$placeholders = 'City1 - City1 - City1 - City2 - City3 - City4 - City4';
$substitutes  = [
'City1' => ['Orlando','Dallas','Atlanta','Detroit','Houston'],
'City2' => ['Jakarta','Bandung','Surabaya','Medan','Makassar','Surabaya'],
'City3' => ['Atlanta','Tampa','Miami','Houston'],
'City4' => ['Mandalay','Caloocan','Hai Phong','Quezon City'],
];
$replacements = [];
foreach($substitutes as $key => $choices) {
    $random_key = array_rand($choices);
    $replacements[$key] = $choices[$random_key];
}
$spun = str_replace(
    array_keys($replacements),
    array_values($replacements),
    $placeholders
);
echo $spun;
?>
```

but the result that i get is the same...

*Result: Orlando - Orlando - Orlando - Bandung - Miami - Caloocan - Caloocan*

I want to make result like this:

*Result: Orlando - Houston - Atlanta - Bandung - Miami - Caloocan - Mandalay*

Please give me a sample code..

Comment: You have repeated values in `$placeholders`. So, `str_replace` match 3 times on **City1** and 2 times on **City4**.

Comment: You can shuffle subarrays and take value from each subarray it one by one.

Comment: How to make subarray? Can you give me sample code ?